# Wikipedia API - Generator query to find categories

Tags: php, bots, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

The following query returns the Wikipedia articles listed as 'Good Articles' (limited to 5 for the sake of the question).

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Good%20article&eilimit=5

This works fine, I get the following result:

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "eicontinue": "0|666",
    "continue": "-||"
},
"query": {
    "embeddedin": [
        {
            "pageid": 12,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Anarchism"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 307,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Abraham Lincoln"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 308,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Aristotle"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 339,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Ayn Rand"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 627,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Agriculture"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to get the categories related to each article, so I tried to use a 'generator' query, as explained here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators

I have built this URL: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=Template:Good%20article&prop=categories

But for some reason, the list of categories is only showing up for the first result.

```
{
"continue": {
    "clcontinue": "12|Articles_with_unsourced_statements_from_July_2019",
    "continue": "||"
},
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "12": {
            "pageid": 12,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Anarchism",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:All articles lacking reliable references"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:All articles with unsourced statements"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Anarchism"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Anti-capitalism"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Anti-fascism"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Articles containing French-language text"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Articles containing Spanish-language text"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Articles lacking reliable references from March 2019"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Articles prone to spam from November 2014"
                },
                {
                    "ns": 14,
                    "title": "Category:Articles with short description"
                }
            ]
        },
        "307": {
            "pageid": 307,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Abraham Lincoln"
        },
        "308": {
            "pageid": 308,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Aristotle"
        },
        "339": {
            "pageid": 339,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Ayn Rand"
        },
        "627": {
            "pageid": 627,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Agriculture"
        },
        "666": {
            "pageid": 666,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Alkali metal"
        },
        "674": {
            "pageid": 674,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Anatomy"
        },
        "736": {
            "pageid": 736,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Albert Einstein"
        },
        "740": {
            "pageid": 740,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Allah"
        },
        "746": {
            "pageid": 746,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Azerbaijan"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the option of using a foreach loop on results of the first query to get all related categories, but I would find it more efficient to have the information I need from one query to the API, if this possible. In addition I would like to understand why only the first result is showing up.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should raise the limit of the category module: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=embeddedin&geititle=Template:Good%20article&prop=categories&cllimit=max

Even that doesn't fully help, there are just too many categories to return them all in one query. Look at the documentation of [query continuation](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=API:Query&oldid=3181853#Continuing_queries) for how to handle that (links to an old version because the current one does not seem to explain the concept clearly).